# External user invite (Share Alfresco)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

i am asking if we can add an extrernal user to a group from the invite page. the idea is to affect directly a new user to a group (e.g: select Group from combo-box like for Role) and then click the button invite to get a new user with selected group.

how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this without any customization because unless user is part of alfresco you can not add them to group. 
You should take a clue from this thread:
[Alfresco Forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/adding-members-without-invites-08132009-0601)